# Embedding CSS into SVG to create pulsating circle

Tags: html, css, svg

Is there a way to embed this Codepen CSS into the SVG to create a standalone SVG file (i.e. icon)? Basically convert the entire Codepen code into 1 single .svg file

[This is the link to the Codepen](https://codepen.io/mbenmos/pen/BvzLoz?editors=1100)

```
<div class="pulse-container">
  <div class="pulse-box">
    <svg class="pulse-svg" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
     <circle class="circle first-circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
     <circle class="circle second-circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
     <circle class="circle third-circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
     <circle class="circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"> </circle>
    </svg>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style), you can use the `<style>` element in a `<svg>`.

On the other hand, note that your Codepen is in **SCSS** and not in **CSS**.

Here is an example where I quickly converted your code into CSS:

```html
<div class="pulse-container">
  <div class="pulse-box">
    <svg class="pulse-svg" width="50px" height="50px" viewBox="0 0 50 50" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    
    <style>
    /* <![CDATA[ */

.pulse-box {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
/* pulse in SVG */
svg.pulse-svg {
  overflow: visible;
}

  svg.pulse-svg .first-circle {
    fill: #f00;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation: pulse-me 3s linear infinite;
  }
 svg.pulse-svg .second-circle {
     fill: #f00;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation: pulse-me 3s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 1s;
  }
 svg.pulse-svg .third-circle {
       fill: #f00;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation: pulse-me 3s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }


/* pulse in CSS */
.pulse-css {
width: 30px;
  height:  30px;
  border-radius:  15px;
  background: tomato;
  position: relative;
}
  .pulse-css:before,
  .pulse-css:after {
    content: "";
    width: 30px;
   height:  30px;
    border-radius:  15px;
    background-color: tomato;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transform: scale(0.5);
    transform-origin: center center;
    animation: pulse-me 3s linear infinite;
  }
  .pulse-css:after {
    animation-delay: 2s;
  }


@keyframes pulse-me {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.1;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 0.09;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(5);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

    /* ]]> */
  </style>
  
      <circle class="circle first-circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
      <circle class="circle second-circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
      <circle class="circle third-circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
      <circle class="circle" fill="#FF6347" cx="25" cy="25" r="25"></circle>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its [supported by all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/style#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. It would be helpful if you try the code as is on codepen. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, the code in Codepen is SCSS, not CSS, you have to convert it to CSS.

Comment: @MBenmos I edited my answer and converted your code into CSS.

Comment: Yes, I tried that (css inside svg) as a standalone svg file but it didn't work.